# Bootstrap carousel shows only first item. What am I missing here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am implementing the bootstrap carousel into my page, however i can only see the first item (containing 3 sections) and not the other two.

In the bootply http://www.bootply.com/A465PmKBRm it is working, but not on my site. Tested it with the versions I am using.

What am I missing here?

```
<div class="row">

                <div id="carousel-content" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                  <!-- Indicators -->
                  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carousel-content" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-content" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-content" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
                  </ol>

                  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                  <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                                    <!-- SINGLE SERVICE -->
                                    <div class="col-md-4 single-service wow fadeIn animated animated animated" data-wow-offset="10" data-wow-duration="1.5s" style="visibility: visible; -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;">
                                        <!-- SERVICE HEADING -->
                                        <h3>text</h3>
                                        <!-- SERVICE DESCRIPTION -->
                                        <p>description</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /END SINGLE SERVICE -->
                                    <!-- SINGLE SERVICE -->
                                    <div class="col-md-4 single-service wow fadeIn animated animated animated" data-wow-offset="10" data-wow-duration="1.5s" style="visibility: visible; -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;">
                                        <!-- SERVICE HEADING -->
                                        <h3>text</h3>
                                        <!-- SERVICE DESCRIPTION -->
                                        <p>description</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /END SINGLE SERVICE -->
                                    <!-- SINGLE SERVICE -->
                                    <div class="col-md-4 single-service wow fadeIn animated animated animated" data-wow-offset="10" data-wow-duration="1.5s" style="visibility: visible; -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;">
                                        <!-- SERVICE HEADING -->
                                        <h3>text</h3>
                                        <!-- SERVICE DESCRIPTION -->
                                        <p>description</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /END SINGLE SERVICE -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                                    <!-- SINGLE SERVICE -->
                                    <div class="col-md-4 single-service wow fadeIn animated animated animated" data-wow-offset="10" data-wow-duration="1.5s" style="visibility: visible; -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;">
                                        <!-- SERVICE HEADING -->
                                        <h3>text</h3>
                                        <!-- SERVICE DESCRIPTION -->
                                        <p>description</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /END SINGLE SERVICE -->
                                    <!-- SINGLE SERVICE -->
                                    <div class="col-md-4 single-service wow fadeIn animated animated animated" data-wow-offset="10" data-wow-duration="1.5s" style="visibility: visible; -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;">
                                        <!-- SERVICE HEADING -->
                                        <h3>text</h3>
                                        <!-- SERVICE DESCRIPTION -->
                                        <p>description</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /END SINGLE SERVICE -->
                                    <!-- SINGLE SERVICE -->
                                    <div class="col-md-4 single-service wow fadeIn animated animated animated" data-wow-offset="10" data-wow-duration="1.5s" style="visibility: visible; -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;">
                                        <!-- SERVICE HEADING -->
                                        <h3>text</h3>
                                        <!-- SERVICE DESCRIPTION -->
                                        <p>description</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /END SINGLE SERVICE -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                                    <!-- SINGLE SERVICE -->
                                    <div class="col-md-4 single-service wow fadeIn animated animated animated" data-wow-offset="10" data-wow-duration="1.5s" style="visibility: visible; -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;">
                                        <!-- SERVICE HEADING -->
                                        <h3>text</h3>
                                        <!-- SERVICE DESCRIPTION -->
                                        <p>description</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /END SINGLE SERVICE -->
                                    <!-- SINGLE SERVICE -->
                                    <div class="col-md-4 single-service wow fadeIn animated animated animated" data-wow-offset="10" data-wow-duration="1.5s" style="visibility: visible; -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;">
                                        <!-- SERVICE HEADING -->
                                        <h3>text</h3>
                                        <!-- SERVICE DESCRIPTION -->
                                        <p>description</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /END SINGLE SERVICE -->
                                    <!-- SINGLE SERVICE -->
                                    <div class="col-md-4 single-service wow fadeIn animated animated animated" data-wow-offset="10" data-wow-duration="1.5s" style="visibility: visible; -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;">
                                        <!-- SERVICE HEADING -->
                                        <h3>text</h3>
                                        <!-- SERVICE DESCRIPTION -->
                                        <p>description</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /END SINGLE SERVICE -->
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <!-- Controls -->
                  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-content" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                  </a>
                  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-content" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                  </a>
                </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: I don't know how we can solve this I'm afraid. You've posted a working version and asked why it's not working. There's obviously something about your live environment that is breaking it. Are there any 404s or JS errors on the page?

Comment: It seems like you are missing bootstrap.js ? So it works on only layout (e.g active class with "display:block" but "display:none" for others without active)

Comment: If you solve your own question the right thing to do is to share your answer so that others may benefit from what you learned.

Comment: 1.It appears you did not add the end js <script> codes </script> || 2. The links

Comment: @Xalloumokkelos Which browser are you using ? check the developer console for any error and include that with your question

Answer (score 10):

As stated by R Lam in a comment already the most likely cause of this is that you're missing `bootstrap.js` or have disabled Javascript execution on your site somehow (e.g. a too strict CSP policy). Check whether any errors are generated in your console and whether Javascript is turned on at all. The reason this is the likely cause is that without Javascript the `bootstrap.css` file will show the first carousel item, but not allow switching to the other items.

Answer (score 1):

THIS ONE IS WORKING!

> 1.It appears you did not add the end js `<script> codes </script>`
>    ||
>   2. The links

```
  <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Working! bootstrap-carousel</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="row">

                    <div id="carousel-content" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                      <!-- Indicators -->
                      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#carousel-content" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-content" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-content" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
                      </ol>

                      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                      <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="item active">
                                        <!-- SINGLE SERVICE -->
                                        <div class="col-md-4 single-service wow fadeIn animated animated animated" data-wow-offset="10" data-wow-duration="1.5s" style="visibility: visible; -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;">
                                            <!-- SERVICE HEADING -->
                                            <h3>text</h3>
                                            <!-- SERVICE DESCRIPTION -->
                                            <p>description</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- /END SINGLE SERVICE -->
                                        <!-- SINGLE SERVICE -->
                                        <div class="col-md-4 single-service wow fadeIn animated animated animated" data-wow-offset="10" data-wow-duration="1.5s" style="visibility: visible; -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;">
                                            <!-- SERVICE HEADING -->
                                            <h3>text</h3>
                                            <!-- SERVICE DESCRIPTION -->
                                            <p>description</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- /END SINGLE SERVICE -->
                                        <!-- SINGLE SERVICE -->
                                        <div class="col-md-4 single-service wow fadeIn animated animated animated" data-wow-offset="10" data-wow-duration="1.5s" style="visibility: visible; -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;">
                                            <!-- SERVICE HEADING -->
                                            <h3>text</h3>
                                            <!-- SERVICE DESCRIPTION -->
                                            <p>description</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- /END SINGLE SERVICE -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                                        <!-- SINGLE SERVICE -->
                                        <div class="col-md-4 single-service wow fadeIn animated animated animated" data-wow-offset="10" data-wow-duration="1.5s" style="visibility: visible; -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;">
                                            <!-- SERVICE HEADING -->
                                            <h3>text</h3>
                                            <!-- SERVICE DESCRIPTION -->
                                            <p>description</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- /END SINGLE SERVICE -->
                                        <!-- SINGLE SERVICE -->
                                        <div class="col-md-4 single-service wow fadeIn animated animated animated" data-wow-offset="10" data-wow-duration="1.5s" style="visibility: visible; -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;">
                                            <!-- SERVICE HEADING -->
                                            <h3>text</h3>
                                            <!-- SERVICE DESCRIPTION -->
                                            <p>description</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- /END SINGLE SERVICE -->
                                        <!-- SINGLE SERVICE -->
                                        <div class="col-md-4 single-service wow fadeIn animated animated animated" data-wow-offset="10" data-wow-duration="1.5s" style="visibility: visible; -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;">
                                            <!-- SERVICE HEADING -->
                                            <h3>text</h3>
                                            <!-- SERVICE DESCRIPTION -->
                                            <p>description</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- /END SINGLE SERVICE -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                                        <!-- SINGLE SERVICE -->
                                        <div class="col-md-4 single-service wow fadeIn animated animated animated" data-wow-offset="10" data-wow-duration="1.5s" style="visibility: visible; -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;">
                                            <!-- SERVICE HEADING -->
                                            <h3>text</h3>
                                            <!-- SERVICE DESCRIPTION -->
                                            <p>description</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- /END SINGLE SERVICE -->
                                        <!-- SINGLE SERVICE -->
                                        <div class="col-md-4 single-service wow fadeIn animated animated animated" data-wow-offset="10" data-wow-duration="1.5s" style="visibility: visible; -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;">
                                            <!-- SERVICE HEADING -->
                                            <h3>text</h3>
                                            <!-- SERVICE DESCRIPTION -->
                                            <p>description</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- /END SINGLE SERVICE -->
                                        <!-- SINGLE SERVICE -->
                                        <div class="col-md-4 single-service wow fadeIn animated animated animated" data-wow-offset="10" data-wow-duration="1.5s" style="visibility: visible; -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;">
                                            <!-- SERVICE HEADING -->
                                            <h3>text</h3>
                                            <!-- SERVICE DESCRIPTION -->
                                            <p>description</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- /END SINGLE SERVICE -->
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <!-- Controls -->
                      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-content" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                      </a>
                      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-content" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                      </a>
                    </div>

            </div>
            <script>
        // sandbox disable popups
        if (window.self !== window.top && window.name!="view1") {;
          window.alert = function(){/*disable alert*/};
          window.confirm = function(){/*disable confirm*/};
          window.prompt = function(){/*disable prompt*/};
          window.open = function(){/*disable open*/};
        }

        // prevent href=# click jump
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
          var links = document.getElementsByTagName("A");
          for(var i=0; i < links.length; i++) {
            if(links[i].href.indexOf('#')!=-1) {
              links[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
              console.debug("prevent href=# click");
                  if (this.hash) {
                    if (this.hash=="#") {
                      e.preventDefault();
                      return false;
                    }
                    else {
                      var el = document.getElementById(this.hash.replace(/#/, ""));
                      if (el) {
                        el.scrollIntoView(true);
                      }
                    }
                  }
                  return false;
              })
            }
          }
        }, false);

      </script>

      <!--scripts loaded here-->

      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the following

(1)Confirm that you referenced already in your code bootstrap.js which is essential and don't forget bootstrap.css .

(2)Check your application and other 3rd part js libraries files especially if you are using bundling and minification. Make sure whatever you are using for your minification is doing it right because if it is not, a lot of your libraries which include bootstrap.js might be messed up and you loose their functionality

(3)Any other JavaScript files you wrote must be checked also for errors.

Please debug you project for JavaScript errors. Lunch chrome browser and press F12, click the console tab in the developer view opened by your F12 command, then open your site in that tab and see if there is any issues with your javascripts files.

As you can see alone your bootstrap carousel works fine but in your site that contains other libraries and probably your own JavaScript files it doesnt work.

If you have more information on the issues with your bootstrap carousel post here and let people support and learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

You just missed some JS files to link with your page,
This example will explane you well, [W3school](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_carousel&stacked=h)